# Checkbox Javascript disable button

Tags: javascript, php, html, checkbox

I have an array of users in php that i send to the view (in laravel) and do a foreach to list all users in table. For now it is ok. I have a "send" button that appear disable but i want to put visible when i click on the checkbox.

[image]

I put this javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Enable = function(val)
{
    var sbmt = document.getElementById("send"); //id of button

    if (val.checked == true)
    {
        sbmt.disabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        sbmt.disabled = true;
    }
}    
</script>
```

and call the function onClick method of checkbox:

```
onclick="Enable(this)"
```

But the problem is when i click on the check box only the first button send works and appear visible. If i click for example in check box of user in position 2,3,4...etc the buttons send of these users stay disabled, only the first appear visible. This code only work to the first position of send button.

I appreciate your help :)

Regards

Comment: Please check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

1. You pass element to function `Enable`, but treat it as value. You should extract value from element before other actions.
2. You hardcoded button id in the function. It shout be passed outside and should differs for each button.

```js
Enable = function(checkbox, btnId)
    {
        document.getElementById(btnId).disabled = !checkbox.checked; // ← !
    }
```

```html
<button id="send1" disabled>SEND</button>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="Enable(this, 'send1')"><br>
<button id="send2" disabled>SEND</button>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="Enable(this, 'send2')"><br>
<button id="send3" disabled>SEND</button>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="Enable(this, 'send3')">
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you are using id element to activate button. 
What you can do is set id for each of your send button while you loop and pass it from your click your function and use it enable it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Enable = function(val, id)
{
    var sbmt = document.getElementById("send-"+ id ); //id of button

    if (val.checked == true)
    {
        sbmt.disabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        sbmt.disabled = true;
    }
}    
</script>
```

and your click button looks like this

```
onclick="Enable(this,id)"
```

Hope you understood.

Comment: `val` variable become undefined now.